# How to adjust inputs for Neural Nets?

Tags: neural-network

I have been wanting to try and make a neural net that controlls a game.
I'm very close to my goal, but yet I feel like I have messed up somewhere!
I'm getting values that are reasonably close to what I'm expecting. But there is one problem...

I decided to try it with the Flappy Bird concept...
I have 3 inputs currently.

> 1) Height from ground (goes toward 1 the closer it gets)
>
> 2) Distance
>   to nearest wall in the top of the screen
>
> 3) ... bottom of the screen.

3 Hidden neurons, and one output.

It kind of jump when it gets to a lower wall. But it ALSO jumps when it reaches a upper wall. Thus hitting it in steath of dropping down lower.

My question really, is there some way of turning that jump into drops insteath?
Or do any of you suspect where I might start looking?
1) I know i have trouble with the sigmoid function. I have no idea how to write it actually. It says

> f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^x)

Can I just swap e with a number or something? What is that character? I never really heard about it in the physics math I had...

The derivative is actually easier it seems.
But this is the right formula, right?

> fd(x) = f(x) * (1 - f(x))

Comment: I would think e here is the base of the natural logarithm. That is e ~= 2.71828.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with neural networks, but IIRC, as long as the function returns a a number between 0 and 1 and is non-linear it should work, however I don't think messing around with the activation function will help much.

How deep is your network, how is it structured and how do you set the value of the weights on your connections?

Comment: Can you also provide sample of data which you feed into NN? As well, tell, which algorithm you use for training?

Comment: if you use the sigmoid function, the power of e must be (-x)

Comment: Hmm, I think I must look into writing the math better.
Currently I'm only getting positive values I THINK. At least the BIAS neurons tend to grow tremendously. (Ex: biasW=48 input1W=3)

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^(-x))
```

is just an approximation of the step function that is also differentiable.

(where `e` is the natural logarithm.)

---

You can find a number of examples of Neural Networks playing Flappy Bird. [For example](https://github.com/heems/flappybird-nn), this developer seems to only use 2 inputs, 2 hidden, and 1 output. His inputs only seem to be distance to the top wall and distance to the bottom wall.

I think this is a better solution than your 3 inputs - "distance from the bottom of the screen" is probably not an effective feature.

Note: This is also dependent on how you are calculating distance to each wall.